# how to get Tests run count on running same testCase for multiple times with different data

Tags: java, junit4, testcase

hi i want to run same testcase for multiple times with different data

for example if i run the same testcase for 3 times with different data it should show

Tests run: 3,failures : 0

when i tried am getting Tests run : 1  failures : 0   only any suggestions?

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class PrimeTest {

```
@Theory
@Test
public void isPrime(int candidate ){
    System.out.println("candidate: "+ candidate );
}
public static @DataPoints int[] candidates = {1,2,3,4};
```

}

Here testcase isPrime is running for 4 times means checking 4 testscenarios but in final result am getting testsRun : 1/1 failures :0  what i need is is should display as
testsrun : 4/4 failures :0

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the different data as parameter to the test and use a data provider to create the data. I little bit of test code would help to make more suggestions...

Comment: hi arne below is the sample code here the testcase is running for 4 times but in report it is showing as runtests : 1/1 failure: 0  what i need is runtests : 4/4 failure: 0 so that you can easily find the failure case...

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class PrimeTest {

 @Theory
 @Test
 public void isPrime(int candidate ){
  System.out.println("candidate: "+ candidate );
 }
 public static @DataPoints int[] candidates = {1,2,3,4};
 
}

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [parameterized](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) tests

Comment: am able to run the testcase for multiple times but am getting tests run as 1 only i should get full count

Comment: but why would that matter ? Can you please clarify how the statement like number of tests run is 4 (say) instead of 1 would help ? Do you want to draw the implication that more number of tests imply better testing, which I think is incorrect. Things like statement,branch, and conditional coverage, give a better idea of how good your unit test covers the code base.